Geometric picture of the geodesic in a low dimensional manifold with a semi-Riemannian metric
In the context of general relativity, the simplest dimensional model consists of two-dimensions.
For a two-dimensional manifold we often use a unit sphere to depict how the physical space is curved. And the geodesics are the shortest path between two points on such a sphere, which are great circle.
But the metric of spacetime is not Riemannian, and an impossibility theorem proves that a unit sphere, with positive constant curvature, cannot admit a semi-Riemannian metric.
Is there any other shape with low dimensions, say a surface with a different curvature than that of the unit sphere, that can give us an intuitive geometric picture of the geodesic path similar to the great circle on the unit sphere?

A metric of Lorentz signature does not embed isometrically in any Riemannian manifold, such as Euclidean three-space. Can you please edit the question to clarify the type of "intuitive geometric picture" you're seeking?

Hint: Think about 1-sheeted hyperbolid in the Minkowski 3-dimensional space.
